# How to draw a barchart with a vertical line

Tags: charts, code-review, code-request

The following code works just fine with a few caveats.

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
cl = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "Cambodia", "Kiribati", 
   "Lao DPR", "Myanmar", "Nepal", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", 
   "Timor-Leste", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu"};
bchart1 = BarChart[
   a,
   ChartLabels -> cl,
   ChartStyle -> LightBlue,
   PlotTheme -> "Business",
   BarOrigin -> Left,
   PlotLabel -> Style["GDP per capita, 2011", Black, Bold, 12],
   BarSpacing -> 0.3,
   AxesLabel -> {"Millions US$"},
   ImageSize -> 350,
   Background -> LightGray
   ];
line1 = ParametricPlot[
   {Mean[a], u}, {u, 0.3, Max[a]},
   PlotRange -> {{0, Max[a]}, {0, Max[a]}},
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Black, Dashed]}
   ];
Show[bchart1, line1]
```

It produces:

[image]

There are three places that need to be corrected.

1. Background color should be a little lighter than it is now;
2. The vertical dashed line is the mean value of the chart values indicated. As one may see, the dashed line does not extend to the edge of the first bar from the top. The line should cover the entire range of the bars and also pass through the horizontal line just a bit and have a label "Average"; and
3. Somehow `AxesLabel` does not place the x-axis label.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13};
cl = {"Afghanistan", "Bangladesh", "Bhutan", "Cambodia", "Kiribati", 
   "Lao DPR", "Myanmar", "Nepal", "Samoa", "Solomon Islands", 
   "Timor-Leste", "Tuvalu", "Vanuatu"};

mu = Mean[a];

bchart1 = BarChart[Tooltip /@ a,
  ChartLabels -> cl,
  ChartStyle -> LightBlue,
  PlotTheme -> "Business",
  BarOrigin -> Left,
  PlotLabel -> Style["GDP per capita, 2011", Black, Bold, 12],
  BarSpacing -> 0.3,
  FrameLabel -> {None, "Millions US$"},
  ImageSize -> 400,
  Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.9], (* adjust to your preference *)
  Epilog -> {Dashed,
    Tooltip[Line[{{mu, -0.005}, {mu, Max[a] + 0.45}}], mu],
    Text["Average", {mu, -0.025}, {0, 1}]},
  PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Added sort capability ([`ReverseSortBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReverseSortBy.html) was introduced in version 12.0; for versions 10.0+, use `SortBy /* Reverse`)

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{sortedData,
   data = Transpose[{cl, a}]},
  sortedData = If[sort > 0, SortBy, ReverseSortBy][data, #[[Abs[sort]]] &];
  bchart1 = BarChart[Tooltip /@ sortedData[[All, 2]],
    ChartLabels -> sortedData[[All, 1]],
    ChartStyle -> LightBlue,
    PlotTheme -> "Business",
    BarOrigin -> Left, 
    PlotLabel -> Style["GDP per capita, 2011",
      Black, Bold, 12],
    BarSpacing -> 0.3,
    FrameLabel -> {None, Row[{Spacer[250], "Millions US$"}]},
    ImageSize -> 400,
    Background -> Lighter[Gray, 0.9],(*adjust to your preference*)
    
    Epilog -> {Dashed, Tooltip[Line[{{mu, -0.005}, {mu, Max[a] + 0.45}}], mu],
       Text["Average", {mu, -0.025}, {0, 1}]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]],
 {{sort, 1, "Sort By"}, {1 -> "Alpha", (-1) -> "Reverse Alpha", 
   2 -> "GDP", (-2) -> "Reverse GDP"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code. It works very nicely. Could you also tell me how to move the X-axis label "Millions US$" to the right of the frame?  Currently, it looks a bit inconvenient.

Comment: Since I have many graphs like this, I want to keep the Y-axis sorted, alphabetically sorted from top to bottom, starting from Afghanistan to Vanuatu at the bottom.